# Rails4, Load ActiveRecord Model not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

My routes.rb file is

```
 namespace(:api){
  resources :open_conversations do
    resources :open_answers, :only => [:index, :create, :destroy]
 end

}
```

and OpenConversation and OpenAnswer controller files

```
class OpenConversation < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :open_answers, :dependent => :destroy
end


class OpenAnswer < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :open_conversation
end
```

And I Load OpenConversation Model into OpenAnswer Controller

```
class Api::OpenAnswersController < Api::ApplicationController

  before_filter :get_conversation

  def get_conversation
    binding.pry
    @con = OpenConversation.find(params[:open_conversation_id])
    @answers = @con.open_answers
  end
end
```

==============
This is IRB debugging log

[6] pry(#)> OpenConversation

=> **Api::OpenConversation**

[7] pry(#)> OpenConversation.find(params[:open_conversation_id])

**NameError: uninitialized constant Api::OpenAnswersController::OpenConversation**

from (pry):6:in `get_conversation'

[8] pry(#)> OpenConversation

**NameError: uninitialized constant Api::OpenAnswersController::OpenConversation**

from (pry):7:in `get_conversation'

[9] pry(#)> OpenConversation.class

NameError: uninitialized constant Api::OpenAnswersController::OpenConversation

from (pry):8:in `get_conversation'

**Why OpenConversation Model load likes Module?**

Comment: Do you have classes defined in your routes file (OpenConversation and OpenAnswer)? Or did you just put them together to have less stuff in your question?

Comment: what is this? routes with controllers and controllers with models and what sort of a syntax is that {}

Comment: @argentum47 mymistake.. route file and sinmply controller files

Answer (score 0):

can u give controllers files tree structure. May be ApplicationController inherited wrongly.

```
class Api::OpenAnswersController < ApplicationController
```

Comment: Correctly "class Api::OpenAnswersController < Api::ApplicationController"  another Model is working, but only OpenConversation not working

Comment: and.. do you know my full controller file tree structure?